# Call a webpage from c# in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I need a way of calling a web page from inside my .net appliction.

But i just want to send a request to the page and not worry about the response.

As there are times when the response can take a while so i dont want it to hang the appliction.

I have been trying in side the page_load event

```
WebClient webC = new WebClient();
Uri newUri = new Uri("http://localhost:49268/dosomething.aspx");
webC.UploadStringAsync(newUri, string.Empty);
```

Even though its set to Async, it still seams to hang as the page wont finish rendering until the threads have finsished

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doak, Was almost there, but each time I put any of the request in a sepreate thread the page still wouldn't render until all the thread had finished running.

The best way I found was adjusting Doak's method, and just sticking a timeout in there and swallowing the error.

I know its a hack but it does work :P

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:49268/dostuff.aspx");
wr.Timeout = 3500;

try
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //We know its going to fail but that dosent matter!!
}
```

Comment: I have found its best to give it 3-5 seconds to time-out.

Comment: Adjust the catch block if you want to know if the timeout was the reason for the exception: `catch (WebException ex) { if (ex.Status!=WebExceptionStatus.Timeout) throw ex; }`

Answer (score 15):

This should work for you:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://some.url.com/some/resource.html"));
```

The WebClient class has events for notifying the caller when the request is completed, but since you don't care there shouldn't be anything else to it.

Comment: I agree it should work but the web page wont render back to the broswer until the threads have finished, so it still hangs

Answer (score 10):

For not having you application to hang you will need to call the method from a Thread.

For the HTTP request without an answer, something like that should do the job:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myMethodThatDoHttp));
    myThread.Start();
public void myMethodThatDoHttp()
{
    HttpWebRequest request  = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www..com");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Look at [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), specifically use the [`DownloadDataAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddataasync.aspx) method to send the request without blocking the rest of the app.

Answer (score 3):

To have this process without interrupting the page flow of your current page I would recommend creating a WCF service that will execute the code for you. Have the service set to use 1 way calls and on the page initiate an Ajax call to the service.

Comment: I like my service and website in the same project and tired to each other, the problem with any windows service is that 1. it can crash, do you write a second service to catch the crash? catch 22 and there is no tired dependency if you move servers / hosts, server gets reset via your ISP, the service can easily be forgotten.

Comment: WCF is often hosted inside IIS, so while sometimes its possible that an app domain could crash ASP.NET and perhaps lose a request or 2 that's not a very often occurrence. I'm not sure what the 2nd part is asking

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataAsync/DownloadFileAsync` in conjunction with `DownloadDataCompleted/DownloadFileCompleted`.

Comment: This still makes the calling thread hang until the async thread has finished.. it shouldn't but it does :/

Answer (score 2):

1. As far as I can see the 'BeginGetResponse'-method and the 'EndGetResponse'-method of the HttpWebRequest-object (gained through the call of WebRequest.Create), resp. the BeginGetRequestStream-/EndGetRequestStream methods, HERE aren't reflected yet, - although they are EXLPLICITLY marked for an "async request" in the docs:

   - [For .Net 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
   - [For .Net 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

   No clue, how that works.
2. If the page to call is on the same IIS/App. as the calling, you could write an Filter, that ends all service for this request to client (Your 'calling' aspx-page), if the map-string contains the spec for the page to call (in ISAPI-cpp: "return SF_STATUS_REQ_FINISHED;") But perhaps Your asp/x/-script-execution in the called page is killed too. Question of check.
3. Consider using  server-side include directives (less conditionable) or dynamically call an .asp file by using Server.Execute.
4. Not really async, but maybe   worthy:                                                                                     State explicitly by an EARLY Response.End() (or similar) IN THE CALLED PAGE to the system, that NO FURTHER RESPONSE is to be expected, mainly NOT to the caller. Then do Your stuff ongoing in the CALLED page's scripts. At least the time-slip to await the sync-call's ending could be minimized by fac of 10, 100 or so.