# Cron job asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, cron

I have a clockIn & clockOut module that records start time & end time for workers from an Asp.NET app.

I want to ask how to do cron job for asp.net application to see if a worker has not entered their time on that date or week and send an email notification to remind them to enter start time and end time.

Comment: I made a series of edits to help, but feel free to revert anything that I got wrong.

Comment: I was trying to figure out what a "corn job" was...

Comment: You could simulate this with some cache expiration callbacks in ASP.NET, but that's probably not the best way.

Comment: telling you won't be safe for work, but be assured once you have had one, you'll never want anything else again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ASP.NET is the wrong tool for the job.  You would be better off either writing a [Console Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438026.aspx) that is run on a scheduled task, or a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that polls on a regular interval. ASP.NET is purely meant for a request/response model.

Either one can access whatever data store the website is reading from/writing to just as easily as the ASP.NET site can.

If you've done neither, the Console Application is by far the simplest to write and implement.  Windows Services aren't all that bad, but involve extra overhead, including difficulty debugging, and the need to go through a [special installation process](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169) as compared to the XCOPY deployment model possible with Console applications.

If you ***REALLY*** want to do it in ASP.NET, you can write an asp.net web page that does this, and use the Windows Scheduled Task to run it.  The Scheduled Task can open up Internet Explorer to a specific page just as easily as it can run any executable.  ***But I wouldn't recommend it***.  You'll forever have to close the IE window when the task is finished, and it's just really a "hackish" solution.  I did it back when I was a pure web developer and didn't know any better, but not since.

Comment: we've all done things like that in our past and we're still trying to forget them. I once used a mouse logger to automate a process and it was of course riddled with errors, not least of which was when the user would change the resolution of the desktop because some other employee liked a different resolution. Sure you could have fixed that other ways, but the real problem was my solution. ;)

Comment: Ok. say if I create console app or Windows Service. can I publish this add-on to data center

Comment: That depends on who's hosting it and how much access you have.  If you don't have the ability to get this set up, and your hostting administrators won't do it for you, then @Chris Farmer's answer is your best option.  Or you can add an ASP.NET Web service to your web app, and call THAT from a machine you control.  The fact that you dont have access to do this type of thing is an important detail that changes the answer completely.

Comment: I can go with console app solution  but for the long run I think I have to create PHP script to do this kind of job,am I right?

Comment: Um.. Not necessarily... Since your question is tagged ASP.NET, I assumed you were a .NET developer.  You can do this kind of job in whatever language you're familiar with.  You can do it on PHP if you like... That may also depend on the host's configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Jeff Atwood posted on the Stack Overflow blog, titled as [Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/), in the early days of this site about a simple way to do background tasks in ASP.NET.  If your tasks are relatively lightweight, this might not be a bad way.  If you have a reason to really want to keep everything inside an existing ASP.NET app, this might be the way to go.

The gist:

1. At startup, add an item to the HttpRuntime.Cache with a fixed expiration.
2. When cache item expires, do your work, such as WebRequest or what have you.
3. Re-add the item to the cache with a fixed expiration.

Comment: +1 - I still wouldn't recommend this - I still think it's the wrong tool for the job, but it will work, and it's a quick and dirty way to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Although its not technically a cron job, from within a website you can get the website to call a set page at X time of the day.

I have done this a few times via a web method call, which is called on the timer from the application start.

Basic explanation is here:
[Call a webpage from c# in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302775/call-a-webpage-from-c-sharp-in-code/303036#303036)